# Using the GetValueOrDefault(...) function on a Dictionary, will the default execute always or only if result is null?

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary

I have a cache dictionary and the GetValueOrDefault(...) is perfect for that case.

```
var myThing = _cache.GetValueOrDefault("key", new Thing());
```

I can't find in the docs if the default is always executed or only when the dictionary resolved null. This is important because in my case constructing Thing has a significant performance impact (it's a game) and I only want to construct it, if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TryGetValue` and put it as follow:

```
// We try to get existing value and only if we don't have it we create a new one
var myThing = _cache.TryGetValue("key", out var existing) ? existing : new Thing();
```

Please, note that when executing a method - `GetValueOrDefault` - in your case, .Net computes arguments, that's why `new Thing()` - the second argument - will be executed.

Comment: That's essentially what the second overload of `GetValueOrDefault` does anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Since I can't use null-coalesce, because it's a Unity-project and that is not supported, I will have to solve it like this. So your response is the best answer. The solution with null-coalesce below is actually a bit "cooler", had it been supported in my case.

Answer (score 5):

**It will always be executed.** That is the semantics of passing a value to a function: the value will first be calculated and then passed.

Instead you could use [the other overload of `GetValueOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.getvalueordefault?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-collectionextensions-getvalueordefault-2(system-collections-generic-ireadonlydictionary((-0-1))-0)) along with a null-coalesce `??`:

```cs
var myThing = _cache.GetValueOrDefault("key") ?? new Thing();
```

This will only execute the second half if the first half returns `null`. The type obviously needs to be nullable, so either a reference type or a nullable value type.

Comment: This won't work if `Thing` is a value type.

Comment: As I said *"The type obviously needs to be nullable, so either a reference type or a nullable value type."*

Comment: Thank you. I can't use null-coalesce, since it's a Unity-project and that is not supported. I will have to solve it with a simple the first answer (a simple manual if).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will be evaluated. That is how parameters are passed to methods. All the parameters must be evaluated before the method can run.

If you don’t want the default value to be evaluated unnecessarily, you can do:

```
_cache.GetValueOrDefault("key") ?? new Thing()
```

This will work if `Thing` is a reference type, whose default value is null, and that there is no actual null values in the dictionary that you want to get. You then use the `??` operator to provide your actual default value.

Unlike method calls, the [`??` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) does not evaluate the RHS if the LHS is non-null.

Comment: Thank you. I can't use null-coalesce, since it's a Unity-project and that is not supported. I will have to solve it with a simple the first answer (a simple manual if).

Answer (score -1):

It will be always executed. It is always going to check if the `HasValue` property is false or true. If it is true, It will return the specific value otherwise a default values will be returned.

> The GetValueOrDefault method returns a value even if the HasValue
> property is false (unlike the Value property, which throws an
> exception). If the HasValue property is false, the method returns the
> default value of the underlying type.

Comment: Wrong function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.getvalueordefault